# Animação no Scroll automático ao clicar em um Anchor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Olá pessoal estou com uma dúvida com **animação** da rolagem automática com o redirecionamento para o `Anchor` no `Html` na mesma pagina  tentei várias alternativas aqui do site não funcionou. Entre elas utilizando bibliotecas do `Jquery`.

No caso eu precisava redirecionar ao clicar no `<a href="#componente">Componente</a>`

Para

`<div id="componente">Esse aqui é o componente</div>`

Só que com animação do scroll descendo lentamente

Comment: Tentou pelo CSS usando `scroll-behavior: smooth;`?

Comment: Nossa muito Obrigado você me ajudou e evitou de eu ficar mais 10 horas quebrando a cabeça nesse problema.

Answer (score 0):

Usando o Jquery você pode fazer uma função e
chamar ela:

Exemplo:

```
rolar_para('#componente'); //chamada

function rolar_para(elemento) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(elemento).offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```